# How to Upgrade WebLogic Server from 12.2.1.3.0 to 12.2.1.4.0

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

What is the best way to upgrade ?
what are the Precautions we need to take ?
challenges we face during upgrade ?
Can any one help me on this it will be really helpful ...
Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the upgrade [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wlupg/intro.html) from Oracle ? Do you need more information about upgrade/update process ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best way is what works best for you. Based on experience I would say install the new version of weblogic in a totally new file system slice (well, if you have the option, on a totally new server but you might not have that choice). Advantage of keeping the new version separate is that you can easily switch over to the older version if things go wrong during the upgrade.
After the installation you will need to work on re-configuring the domain. Follow the documentation carefully but its quite straight-forward.
Usually an issue we encounter while upgrading is with the JDK. But 12.2.1.3 and 12.2.1.4 are so close, I doubt you will run into jdk issues.
These are very high level suggestions. Hope they work out for you. All the best !